# how to use naxio:flash in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to implement a flash message system in a meteor test app with naxio:flash package but no success.
In my template event i do a collection update and, if successfull, i set the message

```
Flash.success('top', 'Updated', 5000);
```

and right after i redirect to a page

```
Router.go('list');
```

In my 'list' template i have

```
{{flash top}}
```

but nothing shows up.
What's the correct use of this package?

Answer (score 0):

`{{flash 'top'}}` must solve the problem and, probably, you want to have your message to be shown after the 'list' template rendered.